# TFS Build - Copy Changed External Files

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are new to TFS (2013 Update 4) and are trying to implement a build process.  Part of the deployment process involves finding a series of external files (namely .sql files) and copying them to a separate folder for the DBA to deploy.

At this time, and for the foreseeable future, this process cannot change.  However, to make things easier, is there a way to have the build definition copy all of the files (from a specific folder tree) that are marked as changed in the associated changeset(s)?

Comment: You might consider running a post build script: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn376353.aspx

Comment: Yes, that example looks to be mostly what I need.  I will start digging through those samples and see what I can come up with.